# Jersey File Download allocLargeObjectIOrArray

Tags: java, file, jakarta-ee, jersey, weblogic

I am trying to serve zip file with rest service using jersey,

```
@PUT
@Path("/product/download")
@Produces({"application/zip"})
public Response getProduct(ProductRequestBean request) {
      ResponseBuilder response =null;
    try {
        file = new File(zip);
         response = Response.ok((Object) file);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return response.build();
}
```

I am getting "allocLargeObjectOrArray: [B, size 4194320" expection
Is there any way to solve this problem ?

Comment: How big is the zip file (only 4 mb?) and how much memory have you allocated to your weblogic server? You can bump up memory settings in `startWebLogic.sh` or `setDomainEnv.sh` Also - where is `zip` defined in the above example